# Typhoon and @objc limitation in protocols

Tags: ios, typhoon

Is there like an official workaround with protocols and types that are not supported in Object C

As an example, I have a protocol that returns a reactive cocoa signal producer

```
public protocol PLoginService {

      func login(username:String,password:String) -> SignalProducer<Bool,NSError>
}
```

If I use @objc on the protocol, then I will get the compiler error that the return type is not supported in Objective C. I will have a lot of constructions like this, so I was wondering what I can do in order to benefit from the Typhoon magic

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Typhoon is a reflective and dynamic dependency injection container, and therefore relies on the full Objective-C run-time. This means that, unfortunately, all protocols that will pass through Typhoon must have the `@objc` directive. Also, anything that Typhoon injects must be an Objective-C compatible type.

We're currently doing R&D on a pure Swift version of Typhoon, and you'd be most welcome to participate in the development of that project on Github.

Comment: I don't have a lot of time these days, but I think I can help. I read the contribution page in the wiki, but I don't know how I can help