# Swift 2 - @objc Protocol that throws an Error

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop, swift2, typhoon

I'm using Typhoon in a Swift project which requires protocols to be marked with @objc. I am attempting to upgrade my project to Swift 2.

In my iOS application, my service layer throws Errors back to the UI. However, despite my best efforts, I get a compile error:

> Type 'ErrorThrower' does not conform to protocol 'Throwable'

```
@objc protocol Throwable {
    func doSomething(someParam:AnyObject) throws
}

@objc class ErrorThrower : NSObject, Throwable {
    func doSomething(someParam: AnyObject) throws {
        NSLog("An error is about to be thrown")
        throw GenericError.Generic
    }
}

enum GenericError : ErrorType {
    case Generic
}
```

I saw this post "[Swift class does not conform to Objective-C protocol with error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832147/swift-class-does-not-conform-to-objective-c-protocol-with-error-handling/31833163#31833163)"

So, that made me try something like this:

```
@objc protocol Throwable {
    func doSomething(someParam:AnyObject) throws
}


class ErrorThrower : NSObject, Throwable {     
    @objc(doSomethingAndReturnError:someParam:)
    func doSomething(someParam: AnyObject) throws {
        NSLog("An error is about to be thrown")
        throw GenericError.Generic
    }
}
```

It doesn't complain about the @objc(...) on the implementation, but it still gives the same non-conforming protocol error.

I also tried this with no luck...

```
@objc protocol Throwable {
    func doSomethingAndReturnError(error:NSErrorPointer, someParam:AnyObject) -> Bool
}
```

What's the proper way in Swift 2 to declare a protocol with @objc and throw an error on methods?

Comment: Some more information on why Typhoon requires `@objc` protocols would probably be relevant here.  I don't think `throws` makes sense for `@objc` protocols...

Comment: [Typhoon and @objc limitation in protocols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661815/typhoon-and-objc-limitation-in-protocols) The answer here explains why Typhoon requires it (from one of the contributors). It seems like if I could just format the method signature in an objective-c friendly way, the link that I referred to should work. But I haven't found the right format yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, from what I researched today, I believe that Swift 2 style exception are incompatible with Objective-C, and therefore will not work with Typhoon.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Well, the compiler says dynamic doesn't apply to protocol functions and makes me remove it. Adding it to the implementation functions produces the same results.

Comment: Oops, ok. Looking again, I now think its something to do with Swift vs ObjC style throws, but in any case I'll scheduled some time to do a proper analysis and provide a detailed recommendation.

Comment: Update: I believe Swift 2 style exceptions won't get along well with the legacy ObjC runtime used by Typhoon.